# Why is $\lim_{n\to\infty} 2^n \Psi\left(\frac{r}{2^n}\right)=0$, for some specific function $\Psi$ defined in the question?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, bounded-variation, p-variation

This comes from the proof of the first theorem in [this](https://fabricebaudoin.wordpress.com/2017/09/13/lecture-5-rough-paths-fall-2017-2/#comment-1380) blog article.

The paths $x:[0,T]\to\mathbb{R}^d$ and $y:[0,T]\to\mathbb{R}^{e\times d}$ are of bounded total variation. The real numbers $p,q>1$ are such that $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}>1$. Finally, $0\leq s\le t\leq T$.

We have the following definitions:
$$\theta := \frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}.$$
$$\omega(s,t):=\|x\|_{p\text{-var}[s,t]}^{1/\theta}\|y\|_{q\text{-var}[s,t]}^{1/\theta}.$$
$$\omega_{\epsilon}(s,t) := \omega(s,t)+\epsilon\left(\|x\|_{1\text{-var}[s,t]}+\|y\|_{1\text{-var}[s,t]}\right).$$
$$\Gamma_{s,t}=\int_s^t(y(u)-y(s))\mathrm{d}x(u).$$
$$\Psi(r) := \sup_{s,u,\omega_{\epsilon}(s,u)\leq r}\|\Gamma_{s,u}\|.$$

It is then claimed that

$$2^n \Psi\left(\frac{r}{2^n}\right)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0.$$

I can see that for any fixed $r$, $\Psi\left(\frac{r}{2^n}\right)$ goes to $0$ as $n$ goes to infinity, as $\omega$ is continuous and $\omega(s,s)=0$. But $2^n$ goes to infinity, so how do we know that $\Psi\left(\frac{r}{2^n}\right)$ goes to zero faster than $2^n$ goes to infinity?

Comment: What is $\Gamma_{s,u}$?

Comment: @Shalop edited to add, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't go deep into the details, but it seems that the author proves that 
$$
\|\Gamma_{s,t}\|\le \frac{1}{\varepsilon^2}\omega_{\varepsilon}(s,t)^2.
$$
Consequently, 
$$
\Psi(r) = \sup_{s,u:\omega_{\varepsilon}(s,u)\leq r}\|\Gamma_{s,u}\|\le \frac{1}{\varepsilon^2}\sup_{s,u:\omega_{\varepsilon}(s,u)\leq r}\omega_{\varepsilon}(s,u)^2\le \frac{r^2}{\varepsilon^2}. 
$$
Therefore, 
$$
2^n \Psi\left(\frac{r}{2^n}\right) \le \frac{r^2}{\varepsilon^2 2^n}\to 0,\ n\to\infty.
$$

Comment: Good ! (+1) :-)